# Scan an already printed value

Tags: c, printf, scanf

I am trying to use a number after it has been taken as input using "scanf" function. For example if I input 2 I want to know how I can use that in the later stages of my code(maybe call another function with it).

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){

    int Input;
    scanf("%d",Input);
    printf("%d", Input);
    //here is the place where I want to use the Input

    return 0;
}
```

In the code example, after command printf how should I further develop the code.

Comment: If this program works, you already took that number and fed it to `printf`. Just feed it to a different function.

Comment: The call to `scanf` is wrong. You must pass a pointer to `Input`, not the value of `Input`.

Comment: I suspect this is an [XY](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) problem, what are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Without printing the value can i use that scanned value for just call a function? @jxh

Comment: Is it nothing more than that ?? oh... :) @sergej thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not sure if this answers your question. You dont have to print the value to use it. you can simply use it anywhere after you have taken it from scanf.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int inc(int input) {
    int val = input + 1;
    return val;
}

int main(){

    int Input;
    scanf("%d",&Input); //dont forget &
    //now you have the input saved, do anything you want with Input
    printf("%d",Input); // you can print the value you scanned
    int out = inc(Input); //you can put it in a new function
    printf("%d %d",Input,out); //you can output it again, "printf" is also another function

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That the thing what i wanted.. thanks for helping  me.. I'm new to cording... :) @AyonNahiyan